# How to change woocommerce no price products style

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to Change the price style for only no price products and only in the single products page.

My problem is this code works for all product price in whole site like archive page, similar products below in single product page and more...

I write and use below code but not work only for single products page:

```
.hide-larger-price .price :not(.price) {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #1975ff;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

I need a code work only for no price product and only in single product page. Not anywhere else...

Comment: you can use body classes. WP / Woo adds different classes by type of page. In your case will be body.single-product .hide-larger-price .price :not(.price) {}

Comment: Thanks. but this code .single-product does not work. you can see my site. please [link](https://vekshop.ir)  and i can't use WP / Woo but i'am not a professional developer. can help me more?

Comment: this should do it - body.single-product.hide-larger-price .price :not(.price)

Comment: @Martin Mirchev Does not work.

Comment: Works for me when i tested it. Currently u have .hide-larger-price.single-product .entry-summary .price > strong either remove it and add body.single-product.hide-larger-price .price :not(.price) {} or call after body.single-product.hide-larger-price .price :not(.price) . Clear you cache check your inspector if everything is as it should be.

Comment: Hi @MartinMirchev . Strong its work for me. Because in the format of my site, products without price have a strong feature. The only difference is strong, otherwise there is no other difference. I mean between priced and unpriced products. Anyway, the problem was solved by defining a special style for the strong property.